# How do I make this C++ code into a function?

Tags: c++

what I'm trying to do is put make 1 function that declares the array (Which I think I got) and the other function to print the array. The code works perfectly right now how it is but I am trying to practice on how to do them while using functions. Can someone help me out? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

//Function Prototypes
void ArrayInt(double&);
void printUser();

int main(){
    double alpha[50]; 

    //Call Function
    ArrayInt(alpha[50]);

    //Start for loop
    for ( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ ){

        if (i < 25){
            alpha[i] = i*i;  
        }
        else{
            alpha[i] = 3 * i; 
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <50; i++){
        if ( (i+1) % 10 == 0 ){  //10 numbers per line
            cout << endl; 
        }
    }

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

void arrayInt(double& ){
    //Declare and Initialize Array
    double alpha[50]; 
}

void printUser(){
    //Output to user
    cout << alpha[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Does this code work perfectly? I'm not sure... I tried to build but it results compile error.

Comment: I think when I erase the void printUser() function, then it works perfectly, sorry about the error

Comment: What's the point of the reference in `arrayInt` if you never use it?

Comment: alpha[50] is in main scope. printUser will not able to reference it... Besides, alpha[50] in ArrayInt is not the alpha[50] in main.

Comment: @djthoms That's the problem, I'm trying to figure out how arrays work.

Comment: @NgKhinHooi  I see, so what can I do to fix that exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

// Function Prototypes
void ArrayInit(double array[]); // you might want to initalize parameter array...
void PrintUser(double value); // you must call this function with parameter

/*
//Function Prototypes
void ArrayInt(double&);
void printUser();
*/

int main(){
    double alpha[50]; 

    //Call Function
//  ArrayInt(alpha[50]); // this is just about alpha[50], not whole array but just double type element
    ArrayInit(alpha);

    /*
    this can be moved to function ArrayInit()

    //Start for loop
    for ( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ ){
            //Start if then statement
            //first 25 is the square of the index variable 'i'
            if (i < 25){
               alpha[i] = i*i;  
            }
            else{
                alpha[i] = 3 * i; 
            }
    } //end for loop
    */

    //Start for loop
    for (int i = 0; i <50; i++){
        //Start if then statement
        PrintUser(alpha[i]); // print user value
        if ( (i+1) % 10 == 0 ){  //10 numbers per line
            cout << endl; 
        } //end if
    } //end for loop

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
  }


// fixed ArrayInit
void ArrayInit(double alpha[]) {
    //Start for loop
    for ( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ ){
            //Start if then statement
            //first 25 is the square of the index variable 'i'
            if (i < 25){
               alpha[i] = i*i;  
            }
            else{
                alpha[i] = 3 * i; 
            }
    } //end for loop
}


void PrintUser(double value){ // print parameter value
    //Output to user
    cout << value << " ";

}
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks so much. But I don't want to just copy and paste this, I actually want to learn and have a good/techniques of making functions. Any resources that could help me out? Thanks @Mr.Handy

Comment: I really find `cplusplus.com` helpful

Comment: Sorry but my mother tongue is not English and my reference is not written in English... (in Korean)
I think cplusplus.com is good too.

Answer (score 1):

Goal 1: 1 function that declares the array

Goal 2: the other function to print the array

How about this: (comments added to clarify)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
void ArrayInt(double**, int);
void printUser(double*);

int main(){

    double *alpha; // Defines a pointer to a double.

    //Call Function
    ArrayInt(&alpha, 50); // Passes a pointer to the variable 'alpha' to the function.
    // OR: alpha = arrayInt2(50); works also

    // Put values in our newly created array ...
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){

        //Start if then statement
        //first 25 is the square of the index variable 'i'
        if (i < 25){
            alpha[i] = i*i;
        }
        else{
            alpha[i] = 3 * i;
        }
    } //end for loop

    printUser(alpha);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


void arrayInt(double* *_alpha, int size) {
    // '*_alpha' makes '_alpha' a pointer to another pointer (in this case
    // a pointer to the variable 'alpha' above).
    //Declare and Initialize Array
    *_alpha = new double[size];
    // In this case, '*_alpha' dereferences the pointer so that when we
    // set a value, it will affect the variable 'alpha' we gave it.
    memset(*_alpha, 0, sizeof(double)*size); // (reset all to 0)
}

double* arrayInt2(int size) {
    //Declare and Initialize Array
    return (double*)memset(new double[size], 0, sizeof(double)*size);
}

void printUser(double* _alpha) {
    // Since we don't need to create and *return* a value back, only a
    // reference to the original array is passed in.

    //Output to user
    //Start for loop
    for (int i = 0; i <50; i++){
        //Start if then statement
        if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0){  //10 numbers per line
            cout << _alpha[i] << " ";
        } //end if
    } //end for loop


    // Note: [0] == *alpha - If you dereference the pointer to double
    // you get the first array entry, which is the same as [0].
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @JamesWilkins but like I said to Mr. Handy, I don't want to just copy and paste the code. I want to know how to actually do it. So is there any resources available that you might know that can help me understand this code so I have a good technique on writing functions? Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, I added more comments to explain it.